# How to use Certificate fingerprint instead of Certificate in .NET toolkit

Tags: c#, .net, saml, onelogin

I am using the OneLogin .NET toolkit for ADFS authentication. In the `AccountSettings.cs` page it's asking for certificate but my client has only provided fingerprint of the certificate.

How can I use the certificate fingerprint in the code?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this relates to OneLogin, but the vanilla .NET call you can use is [FindByThumbPrint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509findtype(v=vs.110).aspx)